# Does Gotrek's axe have a name?

Tags: warhammer-fantasy, gotrek-felix

Felix's sword is often referred to by name as [Karaghul](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/labibliotecadelviejomundo/images/c/c2/Karaghul.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width/270?cb=20140709221018&path-prefix=es), Gotrek's axe is only ever referred to as *Gotrek's axe*.

Does it have a name?

I know where he got it:

> He gained this weapon during his excursion into the northern Chaos Wastes, where he recovered it from the body of the dead son of King Thangrim Firebeard.

But not its name, if it has one.

The Chaos champion [Arek Demonclaw](http://warhammeronline.wikia.com/wiki/Arek_Daemonclaw) has a vision in which:

> We see an ancient dwarf runesmith forging the axe for [Grimnir](http://warhammeronline.wikia.com/wiki/Grimnir).

So it's clearly very important.

If it does have a name and it's somehow a spoiler, please wrap it up in a spoiler tag!

[image]

Here's himself with the axe. *(in his right hand)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name was never revealed, you've pretty much described all we know of the axe, except that:

> Teclis once read the aura of Gotrek, and got that power is flowing from the axe and changing Gotrek into something other than a dwarf.

So we know it was forged as you said, but that is it!
I used to have the model for it as well, and I think it was always just known as "Gotreks Axe" or "Runesmith Axe" in game.

Comment: Its "Runemaster's Axe" not "Runesmiths Axe". Gotreks axe is one of a pair wielded by the Dwarwen god Grimnir. Toghether they are called Axes of Grimnir.

Answer (score 4):

FirstCape is correct. The other is wielded by Thorgrim Grudgebearer as it was passed down before Grimnir left.

If any of you can remember back far enough, they used to have the magic items on cards in the code books. Gotrek's Axe is how it was named there was identical to Thorgrims axe. No armor saves allowed except by magic armor and that was at -3, d3 wounds. The only difference was that Thorgrim's axe also did d6 to trolls and giants, and Gotrek's was d6 against dragons and daemons. Exactly the axe Grimnir would have taken to close the Chaos rift.

Answer (score 2):

It’s one of two axes Grimnir wielded, and is called the Runemaster’s Axe, and when Grimnir passes it on to the Firebeard line Of Karak dum, it became known as the Axe of Valek.

Comment: Do you have any evidence such as quotes that you could [edit] in to back this up?